# Find an explicit conjugacy between their flows. $X' = \begin{bmatrix}-1& 1 \\ 0 & 2\end{bmatrix}X$ and $Y' $...

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Find an explicit conjugacy between their flows. 
$X' = \begin{bmatrix}-1& 1 \\ 0 & 2\end{bmatrix}X$  and   $Y' = \begin{bmatrix}1& 0 \\ 1 & -2\end{bmatrix}Y$

I have no clue how to started ....please help me started

Comment: this may also help you https://math.uc.edu/~meyer/monthly08.pdf

Comment: thank you for it...this is too advanced for me...At this point, I still do not know how to apply conjugacy for this question...

Comment: i have update my answer please see it

Answer (score 1):

we know that solution of system

$x'=Ax$

is following

$u_1*e^{\lambda*t}$

where $u_1$-eigenvector and $\lambda$-eigenvalue,so  you may need to find using eigenvector/eigenvalue solution of both system,general solution

[image]

where $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, ... \lambda_n$

are the eigenvalues of

$\mathbf{A}$;

$\mathbf{u}_1, \mathbf{u}_2, ...  \mathbf{u}_n$

are the respective eigenvectors of $\mathbf{A}$ and $c_1, c_2, ....  c_n $

are constants.you may continue from this

this may help you

http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/HOHomogeneousDE.aspx

http://www.math.byu.edu/~grant/courses/m634/f99/lec29.pdf

you may  look on this

[image]

[image]

EDITED:

eigenvalue of the first system is following

```
A=[-1 1;0 2]

A =

    -1     1
     0     2

>> [V d]=eig(A)

V =

    1.0000    0.3162
         0    0.9487


d =

    -1     0
     0     2
```

there  diagonal elements of $d$ are eigenvalue and  column element of  V are eigenvector,for system $y$

```
y=[1 0;0 -2]

y =

     1     0
     0    -2

>> [V1 D1]=eig(y)

V1 =

     0     1
     1     0


D1 =

    -2     0
     0     1
```

now apply formula please

Comment: Just to clarify the approach for this question...do I need to first find the solution for both matrix first?

Comment: yes and then find such transformation which maps one trajectory to another so that preserve time,if such function exist,it is called conjugacy

Comment: just want to double check before moving forward...the solution that I found for A = $$\begin{bmatrix} -1 & 1 \\ 0 &2\end{bmatrix}$$ is $\phi_t^A = (e^{-t}x_0+\frac{1}{3}y_0(-e^t+e^{2t}), e^{2t}y_0)$, right?

Comment: i had not  found it but find eigenvalue and eigenvector,formula is given above

Comment: i have updated  about eigenvalue and eigenvector